# I can't see group template in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I using Windows 10 and Android Studio 4.1.1. I did invalidate cache.

There was no 'templates' folder in this location and I created it myself:

**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\other**

I placed the group template files in it, but I can't see it from the android studio.